# format exception when using Image.memory to load base64 image in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using this code to load a base64 image stream in flutter:

```
var foregroundImage;
    if(counter.value.iconData != null && counter.value.iconData != "") {
      Uint8List base64Decode(String source) => base64.decode(source);
      Uint8List uint8list = base64Decode(counter.value.iconData);
      foregroundImage = Image.memory(uint8list);
    }else{
      foregroundImage = defaultImage;
    }
```

when the stream like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAACXElEQVR4XsWXTU8TURSGu/AHuOnMlMbYWorKt1sVKDGiIf4BdUUQXWHiAnDXlERd4oJ+4rbFFa5w1fYvNE0wuJIFf8E0bZr2OO+UO7T3ozMEO3OSd3PPued5Z+a2995AQBKaFtV1PfRB041KUAudBzWjbYquqDbmoofVy+zJc4RIJBI3NM1ImpP+ShpeS+iJ3mDwXCsikcjN3hOLk/+nwABrAG49uQdwJrAG3gReDV80aoF5AY/qo/jmTuqtCXNhYoXySa8EdiCoG1U+4ZWwFgIXv3MhyWtyaloYU8l9bejcNDD8T2Z27gGdnPyibrdLpcPvpBtjQg0TcsXSoVWLOZjL13BqwwA/aAsN/pydUX8cHf2QmsAYcv2RyWQpNj4h1PZLaUAGZ8GbkMHz+QKlUrv06fOXoSakBnh4s9mk4+Ofl93p0oQKvrz8hHK5vKVhJgQDMvjLV6+tHBqzOD39Tfcnp6Rw1D58tEDpdMbRxICBmdl5JZwJAMCnZ+aUcKbHC4uCiTuxuNpAsViym7VaLQHOFJ+45whXmdh4+05toHDwzW7Y6XRoc/O90FD1zfk6pqcrzymbzdkG1tbW1QbG43epXq/bjXkT14Unkym6HYmqDahMrL/ZGAlcakBmAmvhKvCVZ+7gSgMQM1Gr1QR4oXAg1DMtLiVcwyGlAQgmyuWyazi0vf3RNRxy3IxgolKtUqPRoL29r0Ke1+rqC9pPp2lra8cRHuxtRu6247HwLWFMJSMUFsbkMrdjLw+jvKwDie9HMt8Ppb4fyxG+X0wQvl7NWPh6Oe0PL6/n/wCHXSY6hk0RUwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

show error `formatexception: invalid character`:

[image]

when I am parse the stream in [web](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), it could parse successfully. why would this happen? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the actual base64 encoded image is after the "base64," word.

Since base64 can not contain comma symbol - you can just split the string by it and take the last part:

```dart
counter.value.iconData.split(',').last
```

Answer (score 1):

`base64Decode` decodes pure base64, remove `data:image/png;base64,` and give rest to `base64Decode` function